# Different Windows Store name for a cordova projects

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps

I would like to localize my Windows Store app to match the most appropriate user language.
This is possible with native application providing different resource files for different languages, but I didn't find a way to do this in cordova projects.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community with Apache Cordova tools 4

Answer (score 0):

As Cordova based projects are wrapped in native apps you do this localization in the same way.

Comment: maybe you are right but there are no facilities in visual studio to create resource files for these kind of project nor the directory structure to place them